# NI sbrio FPGA board does not power up - any leads to debug NI FPGA board?

Tags: fpga, dc, fuses, repair, short-circuit

I accidentally shorted the DC power supply pins on the sbRIO 9612 FPGA board and my DC power supply had a very large current limit. Now, the FPGA board does not power up.
To see if the fuse blew up, I replaced the fuse with a wire to see if the board works now. It did not. Which means, something other than the fuse is not working as well. What could I have possibly fried in NI sbRIO FPGA board when I shorted power terminals? It is a 1000$ board and the service repair quotes 500$. I want to try to fix it by myself, if I can. Does any one have a schematic of NI sbRIO9612 FPGA board or any suggestions on how to proceed with debugging this board.

Comment: it is unclear what you shorted ... it sounds like you shorted the power supply ... how was the board involved?

Comment: Potentially, inductive PSU cable and large dI/dt when removing the short. That could do just about anything to the board.

Comment: So you simply started working on a 1000$ board before even getting hands on the schematic of the board?

Comment: @Mitu Raj Not all vendors provide schematics to their hardware.  NI typically does not provide schematics to their devices.  You'll find block diagrams but not schematics.

Comment: That seems super odd. We work here on 5000$ V7 boards of XIiinx on lab. Without schematics, we can't put hands on them.